# Binding for html select giving me problems if I use property type name for ngModel in Angular 2

Tags: angular, types, binding, html-select

If I use type name binding it doesn't set the default option for select in Angular 2.

```
<select  (change)="changedFilter()" [(ngModel)]="dropdownsSelected.type" name="type" class="form-control">
   <option *ngFor="let type of dropdowns.types" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
  </select>
```

However if I change 'type' for 'tipo' it works:

```
  <select  (change)="changedFilter()" [(ngModel)]="dropdownsSelected.tipo" name="tipo" class="form-control">
   <option *ngFor="let tipo of dropdowns.tipos" [value]="tipo">{{tipo}}</option>
  </select>
```

Do you know if angular 2 has some kind of incompatibility for type name property?

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't. But maybe type is a referenced word you can't use, such as let, var, enum ... ?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge type is a reserved angular 2 keyword so it might not work.